# many images side by side in div background

Tags: html, css, background

I have 4 images and 1 div.

each image is different in their size:

```
img 1 200x400
img 2 600x500
img 3 900x1000
img 4 300x300
```

and div:

```
<style>
#divimgs{
 height:400px;
 width:800px;
}
</style>
```

the problem is, how can I put this 4 images as background in #divimgs, side by side and each image with the same size = height 400 and width 200 (200 per image = 800 width - same divimgs width)

thank you!

Comment: Can you post your html code? If you are trying to achieve this by using inline-block, you need to remove the white space between the opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in CSS3. You have to play with background-position, background-size.

```
#divimg {
background: url("image1.gif"), url("image2.gif"),url("image3.gif"),url("image4.gif");
background-size: 200px 400px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px, 200px 0px, 400px 0px, 600px 0px}
```

Have a look for the property's on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/